# JAVA Reflection invoke method with casting argument failed

Tags: java, android, reflection

I want to call method of a reflection of `okhttp3.Request`. The method to be called is `writeTo(okio.BufferedSink)`.

```
private String getBody(final Object body){
    try {
        final BufferedSink buffer = Okio.buffer((Sink) new Buffer());

        Method methodWriteTo = findMethod(body.getClass(), "writeTo");

        # Not working 
        methodWriteTo.invoke(body, BufferedSink.class.cast(buffer));

        # Not working 
        methodWriteTo.invoke(body, (BufferedSink)buffer);

        String body = buffer.buffer().readUtf8();
        return body;
    } catch (Exception e) {
       ...
    }

    return "";
}
```

I always got `http3.RequestBody$Companion$toRequestBody$1.writeTo argument 1 has type okio.BufferedSink, got okio.RealBufferedSink`.

The `okio.BufferedSink` is interface class, so how can invoke this method with `okio.RealBufferedSink` ?

Comment: Is `method.getParameters()[0] == BufferedSink.class`?

Comment: Class loaders are important too.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn
I added `log(methodWriteTo.getParameters()[0] + " == " + BufferedSink.class)` and the result is `okio.BufferedSink arg0 == interface okio.BufferedSink`.

Comment: Sorry, meant `method.getParameters()[0].getType() == BufferedSink.class`. If you want to compare it by hand (printing it out), then `method.getParameters()[0].getType().getClassLoader() == BufferedSink.class.getClassLoader()`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Class loaders are different. The `buffer` is from my main package and the method is imported by Xposed framework. Any suggest?

Comment: You tagged it android, so you can't use java.lang.reflect.Proxy. In short - make sure that the classes are loaded from the same class loader.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn. Thanks to your guidance, I found `XposedHelpers.findClass` and `XposedHelpers.findConstructor` to help load it from same class loader.